# Peer Dependency Issue with React_Native app Building Pods for IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

When I try to build my app for the app store with EAS build, Expo cannot build podfiles becauses of peer dependencies giving the following error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
    EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 9.5.0) was resolved to 9.5.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 9.5.0)

    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 16.7.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.3.0)
```

Comment: Hi Adam did you find a way to fix it? Have exactly same problem

Answer (score 0):

In folder IOS-> pod update Firebase/CoreOnly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).